# Multi-Dimesnion Array sorting, Udating database until criteria meet then moving to next criteria

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have a php (5.3) file that sets a Multi-Dimensional Array

```
$prices = array(
                  array('at',$ANewPrice2,$ANewMargin,$ACode),
                  array('aB',$ANewPrice2,$ANewMargin,$ACode),
                  array('c', $NPrice2,$NPriceMargin,10),
                  array('d',$BW2,$BWMargin,$BWCode),
                  array('e', $BWU2,$BWUMargin,$BWCodeU),
                  array('f', $BKB2 ,$BKBMargin, $BKBCode),
                  array('g',$FusedPrice2,$FUsedPriceMargin,$FusedCode),
                  array('h',$FNew2,$FNewMargin,$FNewCode),
                  );
```

The letter is the key, the second column is the price, the third column is the margin, and the fourth column is the Qty. So what I need to do is sort them by the highest price (2nd column), and then if the value of the margin>0 then check the 4th column against a variable `$qty` and put the amount of the `$qty` into a variable so that I can insert it into a specific column of a table ( I have the table part and how to insert).

All of this is doable no problem, the kicker is that if the `$qty` is greater than the value of the 4th column then it needs to subtract the value of `$qty` from the value of the 4th column,  go to the next highest price and redo the process and so on and so forth until the value of `$qty` is 0. I know `arsort($prices);` will give me the best guide, but I was wondering if there was an easy way to do this rather than a hundred nested if then statements.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

SO here is what i ended up doing

```
while ($qtyDistribute>0){
     $prices = array(
                  'a' => $Price2,
                  'ab' => $NPrice2,
                  'c'=>$BW2,
                  'd'=>$BWU2,
                  'e'=>$BKB2,
                  'f'=>$Price2,
                  'g'=>$FNew2
                  );
if ($bestGuide=='ab'){
    if($abMargin>0){
        if($qtyDistribute<=10){
            $abQty=$qtyDistribute;
            $qtyDistribute=0;
        }
        else if ($qtyDistribute>10){
            $abQty=10;
            $qtyDistribute=($qtyDistribute-10);
            $NPrice2=0;             
        }
    }
     else{
        $qtyDistribute=0;

    }
}
```

... for each price, so that once it checked the price for the highest it would simple set the price =0 and then run again until all the prices were exhausted or the  qtyDistribute=0

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for `usort`
Firstly define your compare callback:

```
function compare_price($a, $b) {
   //you can do other checks here
   //the function has to return an integer
   return strnatcmp($a[1], $b[1]);
}
```

Then sort:

```
usort($prices, 'compare_price'); //passed by reference
```

Additional documentation and examples: [usort Manual PHP.net](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php)

Comment: i am not having trouble sorting the prices i know which one is the greatest and second best and so on, what i am having trouble with is trying not to do 300,000 if else statements. example if $a is best price then $aqty=max($aqty),  $avalqty=$avalqty-aqty then using the left over quantity to run through bqty then c qty ( the qtys for a,b,c are set by a query result ), so if it is always a price then b price then c price no problem if statement is fine, but what happens when it is a price then c price then bprice ( remember there are 9 price i just showed 3 in the comments

Comment: It's unclear, where are the 9 prices? And what type are these variables: array('at',$ANewPrice2,$ANewMargin,$ACode) ? Are the other prices as more elements in the array or the second column is an array of prices?

Comment: i will post the answer in a few ( simple but could not wrap my brain around it)

Comment: Sorry but this for me makes no sense. I need to understand what are  you trying to do for find a better way to do it. What is the purpose of this code? Your answer also don't use $prices at all, instead uses a lot of external variables which haven't been described what they are supposed to do